# Casual user - trying to understand how to define a recursive population growth formula

Tags: function-construction

I'd like to play around with the sequence

X n+1 = R xn (1-x)

where the n+1 and n are subscripts

I tried writing

```
x[n_] = R x[n - 1] (1 - x)
```

as I didn't know how to define for n+1 but in any case, I can't get any sensible results out of it.

Would appreciate some tips. As I mentioned, I'm just a very casual user, dabble with Mathematica from time to time.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, just a typo, that '=' was meant to be  ':='

Comment: you can edit your question. As for defining `n+1`, think about this: with your current expression you have defined, if you enter in `n+1` for your `n`, you will get the behavior you desire, as the `n-1` would go to `n` (`n+1-1==n`). For this I would look into [`RecurrenceTable`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RecurrenceTable.html)

Comment: is `x` a function head or a variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Clear[x, xx, n, R, seq]
```

Note that you cannot use `x` as both a variable and a function. Using `xx` for the function,

```
xx[0] = x0;

xx[n_] := xx[n] = R xx[n - 1] (1 - x);

seq = xx /@ Range[0, 10]

(* {x0, R (1 - x) x0, R^2 (1 - x)^2 x0, R^3 (1 - x)^3 x0, R^4 (1 - x)^4 x0, 
 R^5 (1 - x)^5 x0, R^6 (1 - x)^6 x0, R^7 (1 - x)^7 x0, R^8 (1 - x)^8 x0, 
 R^9 (1 - x)^9 x0, R^10 (1 - x)^10 x0} *)
```

This sequence can be generalized with [`FindSequenceFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindSequenceFunction.html)

```
FindSequenceFunction[Rest@seq, n]

(* (R - R x)^n x0 *)
```

Or the sequence can be generated using [`RecurrenceTable`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RecurrenceTable.html)

```
Clear[x, xx, n, R]

seq == RecurrenceTable[{xx[n] == R xx[n - 1] (1 - x), xx[0] == x0}, 
  xx[n], {n, 0, 10}]

(* True *)
```

Alternatively, you can find the general solution using [`RSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RSolve.html)

```
Clear[x, xx, n, R]

xx[n] /. RSolve[{xx[n] == R xx[n - 1] (1 - x), xx[0] == x0}, xx, n][[1]]

(* (R - R x)^n x0 *)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer - it's much appreciated